# Grails Hibernate session is cleared out even if the exception at the controller is caught.

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have found that, hibernate session is cleared if there any issue occurred at grails Service and the exception is not caught. I have an interceptor for all controllers where i have a method for database transactions (bad practice to do so). My scenario goes like this:

At AllInterceptor Class :

```
class AllInterceptor {
boolean before() {

def xyz = getValueFromDomain(session.domain);

def getValueFromDomain(def domain)
    {
        DomainB domainb
        try{
            def domainA = DomainA.findByUrl(domain)
            if (domainA){
                domainb = domainA.dwClient
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.warn("Exception occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return domainb
    }
}
}
```

At DashBoardController :

```
getChartData(){

    def chartData = chartService.getChartData();
    if(!chartData){
    render (status : 204)
    }else{
    render chartData as JSON;
}}
```

At chartService :

```
getChartData(){
def chartData = '';
try{
throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception e){

}
return chartData;
}
```

Here, the exception is already caught in the service and also there is no exception at dashboard controller, but again when another controller is called exception is thrown as **org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread** at def xyz = getValueFromDomain(session.domain);

Here i don't understand what is causing the hibernate session to clear. It would have been cleared if the exception at the service was not caught and is propagated but the exception is caught. So why is hibernate session being cleared. Please help !